# Slidetoggle next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, slidetoggle

I have many snippets with a "read more" link, and I'm looking for a way to have the same selectors for all the snippets. I thought that jQuery's next could work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".readmore").click(function () {
        $(".readmore").next().slideToggle("slow", function () {
            $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
        });
    });
});
</script>

Visible text 1<a class="readmore">Read More 1</a><div class="more">Text to appear 1</div>
Visible text 2<a class="readmore">Read More 2</a><div class="more">Text to appear 2</div>
Visible text 3<a class="readmore">Read More 3</a><div class="more">Text to appear 3</div>

<style>.more {display:none}</style>
```

Unfortunately, text for all snippets appears when clicking on one "read more" link, instead of just the next element. What's wrong with the code above?

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/vk61zq1k/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
$(".readmore").click(function () {
    $(".readmore").next()...
```

to

```
$(".readmore").click(function () {
    $(this).next()...
```

so the `next()` selector in the  `click()` event function is only applied to the currently clicked element instead of all elements with the class `readmore` at the same time.

Comment: Wow! Was that simple :) Last thing: is there a way to gently scroll to the "appeared" text instead of just jumping after the slide effect ends?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Glad that I was able to help. About the scrolling - you mean e.g. like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qLvzvvL6/

Comment: Yep that's ok! Would be perfect if the screen could scroll at the same time of the div (now it's after the div has scrolled)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Yes, that's because the scroll is called in the `slideToggle()` callback, meaning it starts when the animation ends. I'll have a look if it could be handled in a different way and drop a comment, but not now as it's getting late here.